# keyword "public" not indented correctly using vscode in c/c++

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

i'm using the default visual studio formatter for c/c++, yet it seems to be formatting the word "public" different, its adding 2 white spaces [(refer to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imv4.png) which as far as i know isn't what the visual studio formatter does by default, there should be no white space, whats wrong with mine ? am i using a different formatter somehow ?

i tried forcing it to use visual studio's style yet still same result, [refer to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeMKL.png) any ideas ?

Comment: go through ALL options of the formatter, if none apply try a different one or don't use one, I have NEVER used a formatter (for C/C++) in all my years

Comment: @rioV8 you aren't getting my concern, MY "visual studio" formatter is formatting different than say my friend's formatter, its like mine is different somehow

and this isn't a formatter i downloaded or something, im talking about the *default* vscode formatter

Comment: `visual studio` and `vscode` are different, most likely also their formatters

Comment: @rioV8 This isn't what i'm referring to, The default vscode formatter is just called "visual studio", but that's besides my point, my point is that MY default vscode formatter, is formatting differently than everyone else's, this isn't how it formats on my friends computer, this isn't what vscode's formatter does by default, why is mine indenting ???

Comment: if all your formatter settings are the same you should file a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed ! i was using the wrong command, it is `"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "Visual Studio",` rather than `_fallbackstyle` :)
[refer to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXHXu.png)